# How to `send_error` from `before` hook at dancer?

Tags: perl, dancer

My dancer version is 1.35.
I can not find correct way to return error to user from `before` hook.

```perl
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use Dancer;

set port => 8080;

hook before => sub {
        Dancer::send_error('Hello', 422 );
};

get '/hello/:name' => sub {
    return "Why, hello there " . param('name');
};

dance;
```

Will result `500 Internal server error` instead of expected `422`

What is correct way to return error from `before` hook?

Comment: What error do you get in the log?

Comment: @ikegami: https://pastebin.com/xihHiZmA

Comment: @ikegami: with this [fix](https://github.com/KES777/Dancer/commit/80b3673ae599c72acc15a9d4749c2590acc71575) it works fine. Seems developers forget to handle that type of continuation. What do you think?

Comment: I don't know Dancer

Comment: Looks like you found it. Add a test and push a PR, I'd say. The old Dancer is not being maintained very well, I think the team have all moved on to D2.